# Example scrapy feed_export to FTP site needed

Tags: python, json, ftp, scrapy

I have a simple scrapy project which is parsing a site and generating a JSON file locally (using the command line). I would like to enhance the project by having it export the JSON tile to an FTP site, having looked at the Scrapy Doc and various forums I understand this is done with FEED_EXPORT but I have no clue where to start.

Does anyone have an example or tutorial I could follow please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for example:

```
scrapy crawl spidername --set FEED_URI=ftp://user:pass@ftp.example.com/path/to/export.csv
```

You can also set the `FEED_URI` in the settings file:

```
FEED_URI="ftp://user:pass@ftp.example.com/path/to/export.csv"
```